# What path do I specify in phpADmin

Tags: php, mysql

My data files are on my desktop and when I run:

```
CREATE TABLE A....


LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/blah.txt'
INTO TABLE
A
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
(l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,444,4444);
```

I get an error. In Mysql system I can do it easily but I how do I do this with phpmyadmin?

Comment: Take a look at the answers posted here: forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=65260#post710388, maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin doesn't run as you. It runs as the webserver user or some other user, so `~` refers to that user's home folder. Just use an absolute path like:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/yourname/blah.txt'
```

Comment: I put an absolute path and it still does not recognize it.

Comment: I use '/Users/-------/Desktop/data/'

Comment: @cool_cs If you're on Windows your absolute path probably uses `\` not `/` and starts with ``C:\``

Comment: I am loading data from a folder on my desktop

Comment: Can you only load local files that are uploaded to the server?

Comment: @cool_cs Yes. If phpmyadmin is on a server (not on your Mac) you need to upload the file to it.

Comment: How do you see the actual path for phpMYADmin

Comment: @What do you mean the path for phpmyadmin? You mean the absolute url to the php pages?

Comment: When I write "~", it refers to "/root". I don't know where root is. I copied my files from my mac desktop to a remote machine(linux) and I assumed that if I put user@remotemachine:/file name it would work but it doesn't.

Comment: @cool_cs `/root` is the root users home directory. `/` is the very top level so it's only one folder down from there. When you write `user@remotemachine:/file` you are trying to write a file in the `/` directory which you probably don't have permissions too (only the root user normally can). Try `user@remotemachine:~/file` which will write the file to `/home/user/file`.

Comment: I still get the same error. Does that mean PHPAdmin is not installed in my local machine? I did this easily when I used mysql in my remote machine to import the data. I cannot do anything with phpadmin.

Comment: @cool_cs so you uploaded the file to `/home/user/file` and then used that absolute path in phpmyadmin?

Comment: I uploaded the file to the directory. Yes, I used 'user@remotemachine:~/file'

Answer (score 0):

Copy that file into phpmyadmin folder and run this query

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'blah.txt' INTO TABLE `tb_name` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'# Affected rows: 1

Comment: So root refers to the phpmyadmin folder?